# How can I add exclusions to this "Double Space After Sentence" code?

Tags: vba, ms-word, sentence

I would like the following code to be more intuitive, so I need to add exclusions for abbreviations like "Dr." or "N.A.S.A.". Also, it should not add spaces to numbers with decimal points. How can I manually add specific exclusions or wildcard exclusions?

```
Sub TwoSpaces()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "([.\?\!]) {1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1  "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

I also don't want to apply this to some sections of the paper, like the bibliography section. Could I make the macro exclude areas that I have marked with "do not check spelling and grammar" using the following code:

```
Selection.NoProofing = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution already ignores decimals because it looks for a single space, which they won't have, and for the bibliography you can just update the field afterward and the added spaces will disappear.

That leaves things like 'Dr.' and 'N.A.S.A.'

I do not think it is possible to exclude areas that have proofing turned off. Instead, have you tried stepping through the find results and checking each one? It sounds like you're going to have a lot of exclusions like this and I don't think modifying the search string is going to be the best way to handle them.

Here's some example C# code:

```
range.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
range.Find.Text = ([.\?\!]) {1,}";
while (range.Find.Execute())
{
    // check each find result: range.Text
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm having trouble figuring out how to manually add specific exceptions. I'm also thinking wildcards can be used to exclude any string of letters that has more than one period, but I'm really bad at this wildcard stuff.

Comment: My suggestion is basically "don't do that", but if you want to continue with that strategy, google 'word wildcards'. It's basically a very limited & specialized regex engine.

Comment: Could something like this be used to ignore such sections: Selection.NoProofing = True